# Angular 8 to PHP Backend

Tags: php, angular, elasticsearch

I'm setting up an Angular App with PHP Backend.
the body is generated in my application. But if I want to send the body to my PHP file via http and file_get_contents('php://input'); im getting a HTTP Error. if i vardump the $json i get an empty string. The Body Query works well if i do it manually via $elasticBody = '{}' in the PHP file.
This is my http.service.ts

```
elastic_url: '../elastic.php'


   Search(body: any): Observable<any> {
    const proxyBody = {
      body: body
    };

     return this.http.post('/path to elastic.php', proxyBody, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    })
  });
 }
```

elastic.php

```
<?php
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
// $elasticBody = $request;
// $elasticBody = $data['body'];

header('Content-type: application/json');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, content-type, access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-methods, access-control-allow-headers');


$ch = curl_init();
$method = "POST";
$url = "http://localhost:9210/fud_fret/_search";

$elasticBody = '{
    "query": {
        "multi_match" : {
            "query" : "test",
            "fields" : ["136_title"]
        }
    }
}';


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 9210);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $elasticBody);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, strtoupper($method));


$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

 print_r($result);
```

Ive found following PHP error in my log: Warning:  Illegal string offset 'body' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/WP/elastic.php on line 46

the body value from angular is an [object Object]. maybe I did a wrong transformation in my PHP file.

Comment: What is the error you are getting in PHP?

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in line 16 elastic.php .  .... line 16 is this one here $elasticBody = $data['body'];

Comment: If i delete/comment out the $elasticbody all works fine. but why ?

Comment: @SathishkumarRakkiasamy I edited my question with the php error.